# How to change Munin's graph colors?

Tags: monitoring, munin, rrdtool

I started to use Munin for monitoring, but I would like to change colors of the graph, which are drawn by the plugin `loggrep`.

Is there any way to specify colors in the config file?

Answer (score 12):

use `fieldname.colour RRGGBB` (take care to use the British English notation of *"colour"* here) in the `config` part of your plugin's output to define a specific color for the graphical representation.

Reference docs: http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/fieldname.colour